# How do I write this IF statement in Excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to build a complicated spreadsheet and I need a statement to do the following:

If C2=R2 and D2 is < T2 then U2, if D2 is >T but T3 but < T4 then U4 if D2 is > T4 but < T5 then U5, if D2 is > T5 but < T6 then U6 BUT if C2 does not equal R2 then S8

I think it needs to be some sort of IF statement, but i am tearing my hair out.

### UPDATE:

Vicky's formula almost worked. I have jigged it a bit and it now looks like this.

```
=IF(C6=$R$3,IF(D6<=0.99,$U$2,IF(AND(D6>0.99,D6<=4.99),$U$3,IF(AND(D6>4.99,D6<=14.99),$U$4,IF(AND(D6>14.99,D3<=29.99),$U$5,IF(AND(D6>29.99,D6<99.99),$U$6,""))))),$S$8)
```

It all works fine until you change the value in cell D6 to say £45 when it still picks up the figure in cell U5.  What do I need to tweak to fix that?

Comment: Jigging is the solution to everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF(AND(D6>14.99,D3<=29.99)
```

you've got a reference to D3 here not D6.

Comment: Thank you i can now relax and have a drink this weekend rather than worrying about this!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
=IF(C2=R2, IF(D2<T2, U2, IF(AND(D2>T3, D2<T4), U4, IF(AND(D2>T4, D2<T5), U5, IF(AND(D2>T5, D2<T6), U6, "")))), S8)
```

Note that I am assuming that "if D2 is >T but T3 but < T4" is a typo for "if D2 is >T3 but < T4" and that if C2=R2 but D2 is not in any of the other ranges you just want the cell left blank.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would normally be expressed as an [IF statement](http://personal-computer-tutor.com/IFstatement.htm).

You could write this as one long complicated set of nested IF statements in your spreadsheet or you could write it in [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#Programming).  The [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) option would be easier to comprehend and therefore easier to maintain, but it would be a slightly steeper learning curve.

Comment: Would definitely reccomend the VBA method for such a complex set of statements.

Maintaining nested IF statements in excel is nasty at the best of times.

Comment: So can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try throwing in an ARRAY if you are trying to settle items in the same row.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed. We welcome technical expertise, but please keep your advertisements in your profile rather than in your posts. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

What you're after is a [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel/HP052093351033.aspx), combined with an [IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel/HP052091181033.aspx)

```
=IF(C2=R2, VLOOKUP(D2, T2:U6, 2, TRUE), S8)
```

This says:

- If C2 = R2

  - find the first row in T2:U6 where the value in the first column is greater than D2
  - return the value in the second column from that row
- otherwise return S8.

Which is equivalent to your initial criteria.

Comment: (the key magic is in the "TRUE", which makes the values in the first column into ranges, which is what you want...)