# Microsoft Excel If Statements

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have altered a statement I got from [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079228/microsoft-excel-2007-if-statements) a bit and it now looks like this:

=IF(C6=$R$3,IF(D6<=0.99,$U$2,IF(AND(D6>0.99,D6<=4.99),$U$3,IF(AND(D6>4.99,D6<=14.99),$U$4,IF(AND(D6>14.99,D3<=29.99),$U$5,IF(AND(D6>29.99,D6<99.99),$U$6,""))))),$S$8)

It all works fine until you change the value in cell D6 to say £45 when it still picks up the figure in cell U5.

Can you or anyone else help me tweak this so that it works? I need a statement to do the following:

If C2=R2 and D2 is < T2 then U2, if D2 is >T but T3 but < T4 then U4 if D2 is > T4 but < T5 then U5, if D2 is > T5 but < T6 then U6 BUT if C2 does not equal R2 then S8

Comment: 1. Please format your code snippet and split across multiple lines; 2. What are you trying to get your formula to do? 3. What does it do instead? 4. Have you got an example of the inputs and resulting outputs?

Comment: Moved content as an update to the original question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079228/microsoft-excel-2007-if-statements

Comment: You really, really, really want a vlookup.

Comment: butterchicken: Excel formats it like that so why shouldn't Rachael? :/

Comment: The AND functions and greater-than tests aren't needed

Comment: and the spurious D3 rather than D6 reference was mentioned in the accepted answer to your other question

Answer (score 2):

Take all your problems and rip them apart:

If C2=R2 and D2 is < T2 then U2, if D2 is >T but T3 but < T4 then U4 if D2 is > T4 but < T5 then U5, if D2 is > T5 but < T6 then U6 BUT if C2 does not equal R2 then S8

Start with this using `NA()` to represent parts which haven't been completed yet (this will show the `#N/A` value in the cell):

```
=IF(C2=R2,NA(),S8)
```

Add the lookup based on D2:

```
=IF(C2=R2,IF(D2<T2,U2,NA()),S8)
```

Assuming that the next part is D2 > T2 and D2 < T3 (althought strictly this formula says D2 >= T2) and result is U3:

```
=IF(C2=R2,IF(D2<T2,U2,IF(D2<T3,U3,NA())),S8)
```

Now add between T3 and T4:

```
=IF(C2=R2,IF(D2<T2,U2,IF(D2<T3,U3,IF(D2<T4,U4,NA()))),S8)
```

Between T4 and T5:

```
=IF(C2=R2,IF(D2<T2,U2,IF(D2<T3,U3,IF(D2<T4,U4,IF(D2<T5,U5,NA())))),S8)
```

Finally between T5 and T6:

```
=IF(C2=R2,IF(D2<T2,U2,IF(D2<T3,U3,IF(D2<T4,U4,IF(D2<T5,U5,IF(D2<T6,U6,NA()))))),S8)
```

We still have `NA()` because you haven't defined the behaviour for C2=R2 and D2 >= T6

---

As Stobor said in the comment to your original question, using `VLOOKUP` would be much better - see http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel/HP052093351033.aspx for details

Your current structure in the T and U columns won't work with `VLOOKUP` because:

> the next largest value that is less
>   than *lookup value* is returned

This would mean that `VLOOKUP` would return `U3` when you wanted `U2`, `U4` instead of `U3` and so on. To solve this you would need to move all of the entries in the U column down by one row, put a dummy value or `=NA()` into U2 and create a value in T7 that was greater than the existing value in T6